# install teleop_base error

Tags: ros, teleop-base, rosaria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

what i download packages:joystick_drivers-1.4.2  control_toolbox  teleop_base
but after i run "rosmake teleop_base",there is nothing in the "bin" files of the above three packages;
and when i run "roslaunch pioneer-joystick.launch",it displays the erro:
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [teleop_base/teleop_base]: Cannot locate node   of type [teleop_base] in package [teleop_base]
[ERROR] [1346561998.121965219]: Couldn't open joystick /dev/input/js2. Will retry every second.
So i donot know how to solve it,hope anyone`s advice!
Remark:my softwares are Ubuntu 11.10,ros-electric
and what does it mean in http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROSARIA/Tutorials/How%20to%20use%20ROSARIA:
"Warning: This Section is Deprecated for Electric
teleop_base is deprecated in ROS Electric, this won't work.
"

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42812/install-teleop_base-error/) by [Ocean](https://answers.ros.org/users/2058/ocean/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2012-09-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It says `teleop_base` is not supported in Electric.

So, you should probably use something else, instead.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0